# Missing CV2 in Docker container

Tags: docker, opencv, dockerfile

I've made the following `Dockerfile` to build a python application:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app

# Install python dependencies
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy sources
ADD . /app

# Run detection
CMD ["detect.py" ]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

The `requirements.txt` file contains only a few dependencies, including `opencv`:

```
opencv-python
opencv-python-headless
filterpy==1.1.0
lap==0.4.0
paho-mqtt==1.5.1
numpy
Pillow
```

Building the Docker image works perfectly.
When I try to run the image, I got the following error:

```
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Seems like the CV2 dependency is not satisfied.

Is there something I missed building the `Dockerfile` ?

I have tried to replace `opencv-python-headless` by `python3-opencv` but there is no matching distribution found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libGL.so.1` could be found in `libgl1`, so you could add next to `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt update; apt install -y libgl1
```

Typically, docker images may remove many libraries to make the size small, these dependencies most probably could be already installed in your host system.

So, for me, I usually use **`dpkg -S` in host system** to find which package I needed, then install them in container:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ dpkg -S libGL.so.1
libgl1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libgl1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
```